# In Tennis rankings what does 10+45 mean in terms of getting ranking points?

Tags: tennis, ranking

I have been figuring out the ranking system in tennis recently. I took a look at [the page for the 2017 Men's singles for the US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_US_Open_(tennis)).

It has the current ranking points for each player, how many points they are defending at the US Open and the minimum number of points they will end up on afterwards (assuming they play and lose one match).

However, one line I could not figure out was:

> 30 | Argentina | Diego Schwartzman | 1,280 | 10+90 | 10+45 | 1,235 | First round vs.

So, he is defending 10+90 points from last year. Last year Diego Schwartzman got knocked out in the first round and did not have to come through qualifying so should have gotten 10 points surely?
Also it says his minimum for this year is 10+45 but surely it should be 10?

He is the only player listed like this (everyone else has 10 as their minimum ranking points) and I can't figure out where the 90 and 45 points come from.

Comment: Folks, please don't get into edit wars on a minor bit of formatting. It's not that important either way in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [Diego Schwartzman's 2016 playing activity](http://www.atpworldtour.com/players/diego-schwartzman/sm37/player-activity?year=2016), he was knocked out in the first round of the US Open. Since the US Open is a 2 week long event, rather than not play any matches for the next 2 weeks, Schwartzman played in a Challenger event being held in Barranquilla, Colombia during the second week of the US Open, where he actually won the tournament and picked up 90 points for doing so. That's where the "+90" comes from because those rankings points will be coming off of his total along with the +10 he got for a first round loss at the 2016 US Open.

As far as the +45 goes, you were able to figure it out as described in your comment on this answer, which at the time of editing my comment here said:

"By the end of the US Open his 90 points from Barranquilla will no longer be valid (as they will be over 52 weeks old). However Schwartzman can still count 18 competitions towards his ranking score and his best non countable event was 45 points from a 250 series event in Sao Paulo"

Comment: Just to add that this has been backed up by Robin Haase being a seed in the US Open (due to the Raonic unfortunately suffering an injury).

Robin Haase is listed as having 10+48 from last year as he was eliminated in round 1 and got to the final of the Alphen Challenger in the second week winning 48 ranking points). Haase is also listed as earning 10+45 points this year due to at least making the first round and his 45 points from the Rotterdam 500 series event in February now counting (as the Alphen result expires).  

So the logic applied to the Schwartzman situation is backed up.